# Which property get changed when we set BringTofront or SendToBackProperty in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a quite a complex windows form which have multiple panel. To set some new functionality on some panel i have to set some panel to bring to front and some to send to back. I don't know which property get set in designer file when i does these action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that is changing is called the zorder of the window. In the designer file it is basically the order in which the child controls are added the the parent control (or the form).
Have a look at [Z-Order of Forms in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611395/z-order-of-forms-in-winforms), it shows the concept in practice with a bit of code.
Let me know if you need more details, i'm happy to add some it it helps you out.

Edit

[image]

```
// 
// Form1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(214, 100);
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2); // *********Note the Order
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
this.Name = "Form1";
this.Text = "Form1";
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```

[image]

```
// 
// Form1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(214, 100);
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1); // *********Note the Order
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
this.Name = "Form1";
this.Text = "Form1";
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: Ok. I were talking about order of panel with in a form. I doesn't find any such thing in my Form's class file or it's designer file

Comment: Sorry, there is no property called zorder in .net. The zorder of the controls are the order in which they are added to thier parent.